# Showing a BottomSheet on a dialog in flutter

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to show a bottom sheet on Dialogs?

```
Dialog(
      child: Container(
          width: 300,
          height: 500,
          child: Stack(children: [
            Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, children: [
              InkWell(
                  child: Image.asset(AppImages.mood_arrow_up, width: 100),
                  onTap: () {
                    showModalBottomSheet(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (builder) {
                          return new Container(
                            height: 350.0,
                            color: Colors.transparent,
                            child: new Container(
                                child: new Center(
                              child: new Text("This is a modal sheet"),
                            )),
                          );
                        });
                  })
            ])
          ])));
```

So I have a dialog at the center of the screen and I want to show a bottom sheet inside the dialog, this code is showing it in the whole scree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to do so, it seems that it's impossible, I created custom bottom sheet with animation.

```
double height = 0;
return Dialog(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    child: StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, setState) => Container(
            width: 300,
            height: 500,
            child: Stack(children: [
              Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10), color: Colors.red)),
              Column(children: [
                Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, children: [
                  IconButton(icon: Image.asset(AppImages.share), iconSize: 35, onPressed: () => pop()),
                  IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.close, color: AppColors.textButton), onPressed: () => pop()),
                ]),
                Spacer(),
                InkWell(
                    child: Image.asset(AppImages.mood_arrow_up, width: 100),
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        if (height == 0)
                          height = 200;
                        else
                          height = 0;
                      });
                    }),
                AnimatedContainer(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                  height: height,
                )
              ])
            ]))));
```